# How to run a remote bash script with arguments from local

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting and having a little trouble.

I'm trying to execute a remote script from local machine.  The script on local machine is passed four arguments, and it executes the following line:

```
ssh $STACK 'bash -l -c "./deploy_intermediate.sh $2 $3 $4"'
```

However, I cannot get $2, $3, and $4 to put out the passed arguments.  Is there any way to be able to access them within single quotes?  What is the best way of executing the above line.

I would really appreciate any help.

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The trick is:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/"$GIT_PRIVKEY" user@"$IP" "bash -s" < localpath/script.sh "$arg1" "$arg2"
```

Comment: "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and **every** expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes,  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .

Answer (score 1):

To pass the parameters you'd have to write:

```
ssh $STACK 'bash -l -c "./deploy_intermediate.sh '$2 $3 $4'"'
```

Thus you make way for the `$i` values to be expanded. Yet, I think you'd probably be able to get the same result by simply running:

```
ssh $STACK "./deploy_intermediate.sh $2 $3 $4"
```

Comment: But it will have surprising results if any of those arguments have whitespace or shell metacharacters in them.

Comment: @rici Then escaping each variable with double quotes should suffice. Something like: `ssh ... "./command \"$1\" \"$2\" ..."`.